# How do I switch my fade animations to slide in /out (translation) animations in a webview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to make my webview links animate within the webview page. Suppose I have a link in the webview,upon click I would like my webview fragment to slide to the next fragment to open up the link and so forth (even when going back).. Currently I am using fade animations for the same, I was wondering how I can switch it to show slide animations? Any clue? Thanks

The code I am using is as follows:

```
public MyWebViewClient(WebViewFragment webViewFragment, WebView webview) {
            super();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            final Animation fade = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            fade.setDuration(200);

            view.startAnimation(fade);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an `AlphaAnimation`, you can simply create a [`TranslateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html).

Your code will end up looking similar to this:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final Animation slide = new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 0);
    slide.setDuration(200);

    view.startAnimation(slide);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to show the animation normally and thru the entire page.Currently it just appears for 1/3rd of the page from the right , it does not slide all the way through

Comment: The first parameter to the constructor is `fromXDelta`. You can adjust this value to change where the the View starts.